# addEventListener problem during Iteration of an array

Tags: javascript

i'm building a project for my boot camp, and i'm stuck in a small quite annoying area.
i have an api where i can make queries to amazon and display products, each product has its own "card" styling and along with it i push each product to an empty array inside the user class constructor if the user select that he wants to add that product to his "profile",
within the user class i have a function called "displayProducts" which basically iterating over that products array, creating a div element, modifying the innerHTML of the element on each iteration and displaying it on the page.
this is the function:

```
        const productSection = document.getElementById('userProducts')
        productSection.innerHTML = ``;
        let div = document.createElement('div')
        if (user.products.length > 0) {
            user.products.forEach((product) => {
                div.innerHTML += `
        <div class="card horizontal">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src=${product.img}>
            </div>

            <div class="card-stacked">
                <div class = "card-content">
                <span class = "card-title"> ${product.title} </span> 
                <p> ${product.rating} rating, ${product.totalReviews} reviews </p>
                <span> Price:${product.price}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action">
                <button class="btn delete-${product.asin}">delete</button> 
            </div>

        </div> 
        `
                deleteButton = div.querySelector(`.delete-${product.asin}`).addEventListener('click', user.delete.bind(product))
                productSection.appendChild(div);
            }
```

The problem is, while adding the event listener to each button - it's af it's only applying the event listener to the **last** product, even though on each stage it select the correct button, i have been at it for over two hours and i'm quite lost.
How do i persist an event listener to each product card?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `container.innerHTML +=`, any existing listeners inside the container will be lost, since the container's contents get re-parsed from the beginning from the new HTML string. An alternative is to use `insertAdjacentHTML`, which does not corrupt existing elements:

```
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
  <div class="card horizontal">
    <div class="card-image">
        <img src=${product.img}>
  // etc
```

Then using `addEventListener` inside the loop will work.

But another issue I'm concerned with is your concatenation of the HTML string with the `products` data. Unless this data is trustworthy, your current code can result in arbitrary code execution, which is a security risk. Instead of interpolating inside the template literal directly. consider selecting the elements afterwards and assigning to their `textContent` (or other attribute) instead. For example, instead of:

```
<img src=${product.img}>
```

append the current `<div>`, then assign to the `src` later. Instead of `insertAdjacentHTML`:

```
const thisCard = div.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
thisCard.className = 'card horizontal';
thisCard.innerHTML = `
    <div class="card-image">
        <img>
    </div>
    // etc
`;
thisCard.querySelector('img').src = product.img;
```

Comment: Oh my god. you are a life saver. it worked, i can not believe there was such a simple solution. thank you so much sir. hope you have a great day. it worked perfectly and did exactly what i needed. Again - thanks.